# show more show less text in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, button, text

I have various texts that each on of them has different length, and I want to display only 3 rows with show more and show less button.
I saw examples on json but this is just a paragraph of text and I dont know how many words are in 3 lines.
the npm show more install is not a possibilty.

```
export type AppState = {
    itemsToShow:number,
    expanded: Boolean
}

state: AppState = {
        itemsToShow:3,
        expanded: false
    }

showMore=(ticketContent:string)=> {
    this.state.itemsToShow === 3 ? (
      this.setState({ itemsToShow: ticketContent.length, expanded: true })
    ) : (
      this.setState({ itemsToShow: 3, expanded: false })
    )};

<div className='content'>{ticket.content.toLocaleString()}</div>
                <div className='content' onClick={()=>this.showMore(ticket.content.toLocaleString())}>
                    {this.state.expanded ? (
                 <span>Show less</span>
                 ) : (
                  <span>Show more</span>
                    )}
                 </div>
```

I try to right something ofcourse it doesnt work and Im looking for ideas how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to add the line-clamp css property as a separate class to the content element when it is not expanded.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/